# Javascript window.onload change text of each id by targeting

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code and want to change text of each id when window loaded by targeting

```js
function change_text() {
  const incList = document.querySelectorAll("[id ^=\'inc_\']");
  [].forEach.call(incList, function() {
    const tID = this.getAttribute("target");
    document.getElementById("inc_" + tID).innerText += tID;
  });
}
window.onload = change_text;
```

```html
<div id="inc_1" target="1">111</div>
<div id="inc_2" target="2">222</div>
<div id="inc_3" target="3">333</div>
<div id="inc_4" target="4">444</div>
<div id="inc_5" target="5">555</div>
```

But it doesn't work. Help, please!

Comment: How can I do that? Can You show?

Comment: `forEach.call` will bind the `this` value to the `forEach` function, _not_ the callback.

Comment: @code it's an old trick to use array methods on `NodeList` though that's less of an issue these days

Comment: @Phil I immediately realized after I posted that. I didn't think of the purpose of `call` as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `this` isn't bind on callback function in `forEach`.

You just need to put the parameter in `callback` function in `forEach`

```js
function change_text() {
  const incList = document.querySelectorAll("[id ^=\'inc_\']");
  [].forEach.call(incList, function(element) {
    const tID = element.getAttribute("target");
    document.getElementById("inc_" + tID).innerText += tID;
  });
}
window.onload = change_text;
```

```html
<div id="inc_1" target="1">111</div>
<div id="inc_2" target="2">222</div>
<div id="inc_3" target="3">333</div>
<div id="inc_4" target="4">444</div>
<div id="inc_5" target="5">555</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "there's no `this` in for loop"?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Just means `this` isn't bind on callback function. I'll improved my answer.

Comment: Word of warning... this can easily produce errors if the elements with matching ID don't exist

Answer (score 3):

`forEach` doesn't bind `this` unless you provide a [thisArg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#thisarg). You should instead use the first parameter passed to the callback function to reference the element.

FYI, the `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll()` provides its own [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method

```js
function change_text() {
  // no need to escape the single-quotes
  document.querySelectorAll("[id^='inc_'][target]").forEach((el) => {
    const tId = el.getAttribute("target");

    // Safely append the new content
    document.getElementById(`inc_${tId}`)?.append("+", tId);
  });
}
window.onload = change_text;
```

```html
<!-- demonstrating different element targets -->
<div id="inc_1" target="2">111</div>
<div id="inc_2" target="3">222</div>
<div id="inc_3" target="4">333</div>
<div id="inc_4" target="5">444</div>
<div id="inc_5" target="1">555</div>

<!-- demonstrating no matching target -->
<div id="inc_6" target="does not exist">No target</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Several problems with this so I'll just mention in the comments.

```js
function change_text() {
  const incList = document.querySelectorAll("[id ^=inc_]"); // no need to use regex
  incList.forEach(div => { // run forEach on your nodelist created above
    // const tID = this.getAttribute("target");
    // document.getElementById("inc_" + tID).innerText += tID; // You already have the div in the loop
    div.innerText = div.dataset.target;
  });
}
window.onload = change_text;
```

```html
<div id="inc_1" data-target="1">111</div> <!-- avoid creating custom attributes like that, use data-attributes instead -->
<div id="inc_2" data-target="2">222</div>
<div id="inc_3" data-target="3">333</div>
<div id="inc_4" data-target="4">444</div>
<div id="inc_5" data-target="5">555</div>
```

Comment: OP wants to append to the text, not overwrite it. They also want to target the element based on the `target` value, not necessarily the same element

Comment: That's not regex. It's just a selector that got unnecessarily escaped.

Comment: Data attributes though, that's a much better idea

Comment: My bad. I didn't understand it correctly. I still don't lol, what is he trying to do. Should've posted an example where they are not related 1:1

Comment: @Whip I changed the HTML in my answer so it wasn't 1:1 for that exact reason :D

Answer (score -2):

Please rewrite like this

```
function change_text() {
   let seed = this;
   const incList = document.querySelectorAll("[id ^=\'inc_\']");
   [].forEach.call(incList, function() {
      const tID = seed.getAttribute("target");
      document.getElementById("inc_" + tID).innerText += tID;
  });
```

}